# Does weak convergence preserve absolute continuity when $ F_n(B) \leq M \lambda(B)$ for all measurable sets $B$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, absolute-continuity

Suppose $\{F_n\}$ is a sequence of probability measures on a compact set $X$ such that there exists a constant $M>0$ that for all $n$ and for any measurable sets $B$, we have
$$
F_n(B) \leq M \lambda(B),
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Further, assume that $F_n$ converges weakly to a probability measure $F$.

It is obvious that for all $n$, $F_n$ is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure.

**Question:** Is $F$ absolutely continuous and does it satisfy
$$
F(B) \leq M \lambda(B),
$$
for all measurable sets $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Let $B$ be any measurable set.  Let $\epsilon > 0$, then by the outer regularity of Lebesgue measure you can find an open set $U$ such that $B \subseteq U$ and $\lambda(U) < \lambda(B) + \epsilon$.  Then by the [portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) we have
$$
F(B) \leq F(U) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} F_n(U) \leq M\lambda(U) \leq M(\lambda(B) + \epsilon).
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this implies the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it is not obvious to me why $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Msad I've replaced my original not-quite-correct solution with a much better one